# React JS services request ASP.Net Core Getting 404 (Not Found) Error

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, axios

I can't continue the flow due to the error in the Startup.cs file on the ASP.NET Core side in the service post operations I made using axios on the React.JS side.

When I have only one Singleton object in Startup.cs it doesn't get any errors and post/get operations work correctly. For example like this,

- services.AddSingleton();

However, when I wanted to post/get multiple different pages, I couldn't update the Startup.cs file and did it right. As an example, when I write as follows, none of my requests are working.

- services.AddSingleton();
- services.AddSingleton();
- services.AddSingleton();

I want all requests made by the client (React.JS) to work. How can I edit my Startup.cs file to receive all my service requests?

When I make a request on the coupon page, I get the following error.

https://localhost:5001/api/coupons/test 404 (Not Found)

**ASP.NET Core
Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSingleton<VendorRegistrationService>();
    services.AddSingleton<CalculateShippingService>();
    services.AddSingleton<CouponsService>();
    

    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ReactPolicy", builder =>
      {
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader();
          //.AllowCredentials();
      }));
}
```

**VendorRegistrationController.cs**

```
Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors("ReactPolicy")]

public class VendorRegistrationController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly ILogger<VendorRegistrationController> _logger;
public readonly VendorRegistrationService vendorRegistrationService;

private static List<VendorRegistration> vendorRegistrationList = new List<VendorRegistration>();


public VendorRegistrationController(VendorRegistrationService vendorRegistrationService, ILogger<VendorRegistrationController> logger)
{
    this.vendorRegistrationService = vendorRegistrationService;
    _logger = logger;
}


[Route("test")]
[HttpPost]
public VendorRegistration Index([FromBody] VendorRegistration vendorRegistration)
{
    vendorRegistrationService.Create(vendorRegistration);
    return vendorRegistration;
}
```

**ReactJS - RegistrationForm.tsx**

```
const handleFormSubmit = async (values: any): Promise<any> => {

const response = axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/vendorregistration/test', 
values).then(res=>{
  console.log('res=>',res); 
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
})
```

};

**UPDATED**
@Panagiotis Kanavos I updated the development after your comment. The service call for VendorRegistration is currently running. However, when I make a service request for the Coupon, I keep getting the 404 (Not Found) error.

- POST https://localhost:5001/api/coupons/test 404 (Not Found)

**CouponsController.cs**

```
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public Coupons PostTest([FromBody] Coupons coupons)
    {
        couponsService.Create(coupons);
        return coupons;
    }
```

**VendorRegistrationController.cs**

```
    [Route("test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public VendorRegistration PostTest([FromBody] VendorRegistration vendorRegistration)
    {
        vendorRegistrationService.Create(vendorRegistration);
        return vendorRegistration;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Index` for POST. `Index` is the historical name of the default HTML page returned when someone browsed to a folder. At first, this contained the contents of the folder, hence `Index`. Most frameworks, including MVC, allow you to use an `Index` method to represent the default `GET` response. Specifically for MVC, `Index` is the default action name specified in route templates

Comment: There's no reason to use `Index` even for `GET`. The default route template will match the `action` part with an action name. When there's no action part, the HTTP verb is used, eg a POST to the folder/controller will call the `Post` action. In `https://localhost:5001/api/vendorregistration/test` the action part is `test`. To handle a `POST` to `test` add a `PostTest` action

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the method naming for the VendorRegistrationController.cs and CouponsController.cs pages to PostTest and updated my question as well. But I still get 404 (Not Found) error for Coupons request.

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562610/7687666)

Comment: @Jason When I make a service call from only one controller, there is no problem. However, when I work with more than one controller, I think there is an error in the code flow in Startup.cs.